# Не получается TRIGGER AFTER в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

Создал триггер:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER concert_prime
AFTER INSERT ON concert
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE concert
SET name = CONTACT(NEW.name, ' Премьера!')
WHERE concert_id = NEW.concert_id;
END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

При попытке ввести новые данные в таблицу возникает ошибка: **ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION kassa_teatr.CONTACT does not exist.**
Помогите разобраться, в чем ошибка.

Триггер обязательно должен быть AFTER.

Comment: Допустил глупую ошибку. Вместо команды CONCAT, использовал несуществующую команду CONTACT. В следующий раз буду внимательнее.